# Discover a service's binary path using the command line

Tags: windows, services

In windows, how can find out the binary path of a service using the command line?

Comment: Here [is solution](http://serverfault.com/questions/333904/how-can-i-get-the-path-to-a-windows-service-executable-without-using-sc-qc) at the serverfault.

Answer (score 3):

From command prompt execute this:

```
sc qc "service name"
```

Answer (score 2):

To complete @joeqwewrty's answer, You can use:

```
sc qc "Service Name" 5000 | find "BINARY_PATH_NAME"
```

And if you have *Display Name* use:

```
sc getkeyname "Display Name"
```